can't return value inside an if-then statement in a for-loop
Goal
To write a pgfmath function then returns the highest power d of a given base b dividing a given integer n.  (i.e. input: b, n, output: d such that bᵈ | n but bᵈ⁺¹ ∤ n).  The case when n = 0 doesn't interest me.
Attempt

Use a "while-loop" with the condition to stay \r = mod(\tempnum, \b) == 0
In each iteration (already verified divisibility by b)

\tempnum ← \tempnum / b divide the current number by b
\d ← \d + 1 increment the result to be returned by one



\documentclass[preview, margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\tikzmath{
    int \mynum, \mybase, \highestPow;
    \mynum = 10;
    \mybase = 2;
    function highestPow(\n, \b) {
        if \n == 0 then {return 0;};
        int \d, \tempnum;
        \d = 0;
        \tempnum = \n;
        for \i in {1,...,\tempnum} {
            int \r;
            \r = mod(\tempnum,\b);
            if \r > 0 then {return \d;};
            print {$n = \tempnum$, $d = \d$, $r = \r$};
            print \newline;
            \d = \d + 1;
            \tempnum = \tempnum / \b;
        };
        return \d;
    };
    \highestPow = highestPow(\mynum, \mybase);
    print {The highest power of \mybase{} that divides \mynum{} is \highestPow};
}
\end{document}

The two print lines are for debugging purposes.
Expected result
n = 10, d = 0, r = 0
n = 5, d = 1, r = 1
The highest power of 2 that divides 10 is 1.

Actual result

Question

Why the {return \d;} isn't running?
How can I fix this logic error?

Appendix
I need this function to draw the Cantor set.
\documentclass[preview, margin=2pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6]
\pgfmathsetmacro\myN{5}  % number of levels (i.e. Cantor)
\pgfmathsetmacro\myRowSep{0.2}  % display (non-math) parameter for row separation
\pgfmathsetmacro\myLblSep{1pt}  % display (non-math) parameter for label separation
\tikzmath{ % auxiliary function to find out highest dividing power
    function highestPow(\n, \b) {
        if \n == 0 then {return 0;};
        int \d, \tempnum;
        \d = 0;
        \tempnum = \n;
        for \i in {1,...,\tempnum} {
            if mod(\tempnum,\b) == 0 then { \d = \d + 1; \tempnum = \tempnum / \b; };
        };
        return \d;
    };
}
\foreach \row in {0,...,\myN} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\numInt{2^\row}  % number of intervals
    \pgfmathsetmacro\intLen{pow(1/3,\row)}  % interval length
    \pgfmathsetmacro\vpos{-\myRowSep*\row}  % display (non-math) param for vertical position
    \node[left=\myLblSep] at (0, \vpos) {$C_\row$};
    % use 1/3 instead of 3 as base to avoid too large value
    \foreach \col [evaluate=\col as \curStep using {\displacement+\intLen+pow(1/3,\row-highestPow(\col,2))},
        remember=\curStep as \displacement (initially 0)] in {1,...,\numInt} {
        \draw (\displacement, \vpos) -- ++(\intLen, 0);
    }
}
  \node[above] at (current bounding box.north) {Cantor set $C = \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} C_n$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


and also Cantor function.
\documentclass[preview, margin=2pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6]
\pgfmathsetmacro\myN{8}  % number of levels, must be greater than one
\pgfmathsetmacro\myRowSep{0.5^\myN}  % row separation
\pgfmathsetmacro\myLblSep{1pt}  % display (non-math) parameter for label separation
\pgfmathsetmacro\myPadding{.05} % display (non-math) parameter for extra axis length

\draw[help lines, step=0.05cm] (0,0) grid (1,1);
% x-axis
\draw[thick] [->] (-\myPadding,0) -- (1+\myPadding,0) node [right] {$x$};
\foreach \x in {0,0.111,...,1} {
  \draw[xshift=\x cm, opacity=.5] (0pt,-.5pt)--(0pt,.5pt);
};
% y-axis
\draw[thick] [->] (0,-\myPadding) -- (0,1+\myPadding) node [above] {$y$};
\foreach \y in {0,0.0625,...,1} {
  \draw[yshift=\y cm, opacity=.5] (-.5pt,0pt)--(.5pt,0pt);
};
% tick labels
\path (0,0) node[below left] {$O$};
\foreach \x in {1/3, 2/3, 1} {\node[below] at (\x,0) {$\x$};};
\foreach \y in {1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 1} {\node[left] at (0,\y) {$\y$};};

\tikzmath{ % auxiliary function to find out highest dividing power
    function highestPow(\n, \b) {
        if \n == 0 then {return 0;};
        int \d, \tempnum;
        \d = 0;
        \tempnum = \n;
        for \i in {1,...,\tempnum} {
            if mod(\tempnum,\b) == 0 then { \d = \d + 1; \tempnum = \tempnum / \b; };
        };
        return \d;
    };
}
\pgfmathsetmacro\numInt{2^\myN-1}  % number of intervals
\pgfmathsetmacro\intLen{pow(1/3,\myN)}  % interval length
% use 1/3 instead of 3 as base to avoid too large value
\foreach \col [evaluate=\col as \curStep using {\displacement+\intLen+pow(1/3,\myN-highestPow(\col,2))},
    remember=\curStep as \displacement (initially 0)] in {1,...,\numInt} {
    \draw (\displacement+\intLen, \col*\myRowSep) -- ++({pow(1/3,\myN-highestPow(\col,2))}, 0);
};
\node[above] at (current bounding box.north) {Cantor function $c(x)$ with $n = \myN$};
\node[above] at (current bounding box.north) {Step function approximation for};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


P.S. Image drawn with @Marjin's workaround.

You're not stopping the loop when the remainder is positive.

Quick workaround: stay in the loop but skip the increments when you find the first r!=0, i.e., if \r == 0 then { \d = \d + 1; \tempnum = \tempnum / \b; };

@egreg how to stop this for loop?  i tried using break; but i couldn't manage it

@Marijn +1 but i would like to have a quicker algo cuz i intend to use it for drawing stuff related to cantor set and cantor function
